# How to blank JTextfield after input

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield

I am writing a program and I want the JTextfield to be blank after the input has been given.
For example; user inputs a number, he presses the add button and the textfield should be blank again and should not contain the number. I tried using `null` but it doesnt work. If you need the code tell me, I will edit it.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: `null` will work if used correctly

Comment: [The many, many similar questions that can easily be found](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+clear+jtextfield).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do 
textfieldname.setText("");